# Catching server side errors inside Ajax form submission

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

I am working with a Java application, and I have ajax form submission from a modal window. 
I would like the code to load either success or error page in the modal depending on the server side processing results. The following code is working for the success scenario only.

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: action,
                data: params,
                success: function() {
                    $("#p_content").load("/test.jsp?id=12345");
                }
            });
```

I am fairly new to ajax, but from what I understand it is not enough to add the "error:" portion to the script above, it will not detect errors in my servlet code. Is there any way I can read a request parameter from inside this function? Or perhaps I can use something else? Please help!

Thanks,
natasha

Comment: Since you don't want to modify the existing java code, you also need to tell us what that java code does when it has an error. For instance, perhaps when it gets an error it returns an HTTP 500 error code. Or perhaps it returns a successful HTTP response with an HTML page that has certain text in it indicating the error. Unless we know HOW it behaves with errors, we can't tell you how to detect and respond to that. HTTP by itself doesn't have something called an "error message parameter", so it must be something added over and above the basic standards.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example done in php. Hope it is useful.

```
<html><!-- This is index.php -->
    <head>
        <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script><!-- link to jQuery -->
        <script language="javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('input#send').click(function(){
                /* Empty div#error and div#result incase they contain info from the last submission */
                $('#error').empty('');
                $('#result').empty('');
                /* Client-side validation */
                var name = $("input#name").val();
                var age = $("input#age").val();
                if (name==''){
                    alert('Insert your name.');
                }
                else if (age==''){
                    alert('Insert your age.');
                } else { 
                    var params = 'name=' + name + '&age=' + age;   
                    $.ajax({        
                         url:'b.php',        
                         type:'post',                 
                         dataType:'html',            
                         data:params,
                         cache: false,            
                         success:data     
                         }); 
                    function data (html) {
                        var $html = $( html ); // create DOM elements in a jQuery object
                        /* Return errors from 'b.php' */
                        $html.filter('#err').appendTo("#error");
                        /* Return valid Post */
                        $html.filter('#res').appendTo("#result");
                        /* Clear name input */
                        $('input#name').val('');
                        /* Clear age input */
                        $('input#age').val('');
                    }
                }
            }); 
        }); 
        </script>
        <style type='text/css'>
            #error{
                color:maroon;
                font-weight:bold;
            }
            #result{
                color:green;
                font-weight:bold;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="error"></div><!-- View Errors -->
        <div id="result"></div><!-- View valid Post -->
        <input type='text' name='name' id="name" value='' /><br/ >
        <input type='text' name='age' id="age" value='' /><br/ >
        <input type='submit' name='send' id="send" value='Send' />
    </body>
</html>
```

---

```
<?php /* This is b.php */
if(($_POST['name']=='')||($_POST['age']=='')){
    $error = '<div id="err">Error: Fill in ALL fields.</div>';
} elseif(is_numeric($_POST['name'])){
    $error = '<div id="err">Error: Name should NOT contain numbers.</div>';
} elseif(!is_numeric($_POST['age'])){
    $error = '<div id="err">Error: Age should ONLY contain numbers.</div>';
} else{
    $result = '<div id="res">Hi '.$_POST['name'].', you are '.$_POST['age'].' years old.</div>';
}
echo $error;
echo $result;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your servlet should return the appropriate [HTTP status code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) when something unexpected occurs (usually 500).  jQuery will invoke your `error` callback function when the server responds with a problematic status code.

Comment: I do not want to modify existing java code which is used elsewhere. The servlet sets the error message parameter and redirects back to error page, or redirects to success. I was hoping to retrieve the error message parameter and determine which html to load based on that value.

Comment: Well, you are going to have to modify it to make it work with AJAX.  Bottom line.  Now if you don't want to mess with anything that is already using it, have your ajax send it a special parameter (indicating it is an AJAX request), and change the servlet to look for this new parameter and react accordingly.  If the new parameter is not there, have the servlet continue doing what it is doing now.  AJAX is not just client-side code, you have to work on both ends of the wire to get things to play nicely.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot avoid sending an apparent HTTP success code (1xx, 2xx or 3xx) even when an error occurs server-side, then jQuery will always call your `success` function. You'll need to inspect the data sent back in you client-side (JS) code, to determine what you do with the returned information in the browser.